# Conditional configuration in Jenkins

Tags: build, hudson, jenkins

I have a Jenkins configuration X that is triggered once a night and should copy last successful build artifacts from another configuration Y and process it.

I want to somehow prevent the trigger if since last successful run of conf X there was no successful run of job Y (and hence - no new artifacts to process).

Do you know of a good easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of plugins you might find useful
Conditional Build Step 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin
and Parameterized Trigger
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin